# Data from two years in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

My table looks like this:

```
Period     Value
01.02.2019  100
01.02.2020  0
01.02.2020  1
01.02.2019  50
01.02.2019  50
01.03.2018  50
```

Now I need **one** query, which sums the values for a given year and month and the values from last year and the given month and the difference of both

Given input Year=2020, Month=02

Expected output:

```
Actual, PreviousYear, Diff
1       200           -199
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into anything? If you have, what is causing you issue? This should be a pretty straight forward thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(case when year(period) = 2020 then value end) actual,
    sum(case when year(period) = 2019 then value end) previous_year,
    sum(case when year(period) = 2020 then value else -value end) diff
from mytable
where year(period) in (2020, 2019) and month(period) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is always at least one record in every month:

```
with months as (
   SELECT period, sum(Value) as Actual
   FROM [MyTable]
   GROUP BY period
)
select period, actual,
    LAG(actual, 12) OVER (ORDER BY period) As PreviousYear,
    actual - LAG(actual, 12) OVER (ORDER BY period) As Diff
FROM months
WHERE YEAR(period) = 2020 AND MONTH(period) = 2
ORDER BY period
```

If that assumption doesn't hold, we need more information about the possible kinds of values in the `period` column.